# C++ QuickSort implementation that sorts everything but a single element

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

This is my first time writing C++. I am trying to implement QuickSort referencing the [MIT open course ware slides](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-4-quicksort-randomized-algorithms/lec4.pdf) (Slides 4 and 17 specifically).

However, there is a bug:

```
input:  6 10 13 5 8 3 2 11 
output: 2 5 3 6 8 11 10 13
```

I'm not sure why the `5` is out of place. My code seems to mirror the slides perfectly.

```
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void print_array(T &arr) {
    for (int i : arr) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int partition(int* a, int p, int q) {
    int x = a[p];
    int i = p;
    for (int j = p+1; j < q; j++) {
        if (a[j] <= x) {
            i++;
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(a[p], a[i]);
    return i;
}

void quicksort(int* a, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(a, p, r);
        quicksort(a, p, q-1);
        quicksort(a, q+1, r);
    }
}

int main() {
    int keys[8] = {6, 10, 13, 5, 8, 3, 2, 11};
    print_array(keys);
    quicksort(keys, 0, 8);
    print_array(keys);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass the wrong parameters in `void quicksort(int* a, int p, int r)`, it seems like that you want to use `[a, b)` presentation, but you use some other presentation, like `[a, b]`, so simply replace `quicksort(a, p, q - 1)` with `quicksort(a, p, q)`.

Comment: Also, try using a debugger next time :)

Comment: There're 2 ways to fix this, the method I use is just one of them. The other method is: I. Replace `quicksort(keys, 0, 8)` wtih `quicksort(keys, 0, 7)`, and II. replace `for (int j = p+1; j < q; j++)` with `for (int j = p+1; j <= q; j++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide says `for j ← p + 1 to q`, which you turned to `for (int j = p+1; j < q; j++)`. This is an off-by-one error.